# Implement different themes using styled components

Tags: javascript, styled-components

I decided to switch to styled-components and now I'm really struggling to make my dark/light theme work again. Before I used only css and relied upon css variables. I looked many tutorials and example for styled-components but the theme is always stored and changed on app/top component, while I preferably need it stored in the config component and rendered on another.

How could I do this without necessarily changing the structure ?

```js
import * as sc from "./styles";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <sc.globalStyles />
      <sc.title>My app</sc.title>
      <Configuration />
    </>
  );
}

function Configuration() {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState(
    retrieveFromStorage("configuration") ?? {
      //other things
      useDarkTheme: true,
    }
  )

  useEffect(() => setToStorage(config, "configuration"), [config]);

  const handleConfig = ({ target: { type, name, value, checked } }) => {
    setConfig(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: type === "select-one" ? value : checked,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <sc.options>
        <summary title="set your config">Options:</summary>
        {/*other things*/}
      </sc.options>
      <Theme useDarkTheme={config.useDarkTheme} handleInput={handleConfig} />
    </>
  );
}

function Theme({ useDarkTheme, handleInput }) {
  React.useEffect(
    () => (useDarkTheme ? console.log("should be dark") : console.log("should be light")),
    [useDarkTheme]
  );

  return (
    <sc.theme>
      ☀️
      <sc.toogleSwitch>
        <sc.toogleTheme
          type="checkbox"
          name="useDarkTheme"
          id="toogle"
          defaultChecked={useDarkTheme}
          onChange={handleInput}
        />
        <sc.themeLabel htmlFor="toogle" />
      </sc.toogleSwitch>
      
    </sc.theme>
  );
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you create a small working example here, demonstrating your problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I mean I just need someone to tell me how to implement two different  themes in my entire app. 
You can add whatever css values of other jsx to demonstrate that it actually works, but I would just need my original structure to remain the same (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiarized with React's Context API? From [styled-components docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming):

> `styled-components` has full theming support by exporting a `<ThemeProvider>` wrapper component. This component provides a theme to all React components underneath itself via the context API.

Let's see how we could implement a `ThemeProvider` with `styled-components`.

###### 1. First we need to create a Context to encapsulate our theming logic

We should also create a "custom hook" to ease access to our context throughout our app.

`theme-context.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  // our theme object
  theme: {},
  // our color modes ('dark' || 'light')
  colorMode: '',
  // a method to toggle our theme from `dark` to `light` and vice-versa
  setColorMode: () => null,
})

// export our custom hook for quick access to our context
export function useTheme() {
  return React.useContext(ThemeContext)
}
```

###### 2. Now we need to extend `styled-components` native `<ThemeProvider>` to create our own ThemeProvider

Since we'll need access to our themes, I'll add two very contrived theme objects (for the sake of simplicity) as well.

`theme-provider.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider as StyledProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { ThemeContext } from './theme-context'

// our theme objects
const lightTheme = { colorMode: 'light', bg: '#fff', text: '#000' }
const darkTheme = { colorMode: 'dark', bg: '#000', text: '#fff' }

// our iterable theme "store"
const myThemes = [lightTheme, darkTheme]

// our default color mode
const defaultColorMode = 'light'

const ThemeProvider = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  // get fallback values from the parent ThemeProvider (if exists)
  const {
    theme: fallbackTheme,
    colorMode: fallbackColorMode,
  } = useTheme()

  // initialize our state
  const theme = props.theme ?? fallbackTheme
  const [colorMode, setColorMode] = React.useState(
    props.colorMode ?? fallbackColorMode ?? defaultColorMode,
  )

  // memoize the current theme
  const resolvedTheme = React.useMemo(() => {
    const theme = myThemes.find(t => t.colorMode === colorMode)
    if (theme) return theme
    return lightTheme
  }, [theme, myThemes, colorMode])

  // update our state if props change
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setColorMode(props.colorMode ?? fallbackColorMode ?? defaultColorMode)
  }, [props.colorMode, fallbackColorMode])

 return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme: resolvedTheme,
        colorMode,
        setColorMode,
      }}
    >
      <StyledProvider theme={resolvedTheme}>{children}</StyledProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ThemeProvider
```

###### 3. Our final step is wrapping up our main `<App />` component within our `ThemeProvider`

`app.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import ThemeProvider from './theme-provider'

const App = () => {
  const [themeType, setThemeType] = React.useState('light')
  const switchThemes = () => {
    setThemeType(last => (last === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'))
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider colorMode={themeType}>
      <MySwitch onClick={switchThemes} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

And that's it. We should now be able to toggle our theme by clicking on `MySwitch`. Hope that helps!

Let me know how it goes? Cheers